# Azure Logic Apps (Standard) - Why don't triggers on session based service bus subscriptions fire?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-app-standard

Does Azure Logic Apps (Standard) support receiving messages from Service Bus subscriptions with sessions enabled?

I have tested the "When messages are available in a topic subscription" trigger in Logic Apps (standard)

[image: When messages are available in a topic subscription]

The trigger doesn't fire if the subscription is session based, but does fire if it is not - my conclusion is that the connector doesn't yet support this for the "standard" flavour logc app.

Comment: This doc refers to logic apps supporting sessions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can built service bus trigger and using session handling in Logic app(Standard) [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/azure-logic-apps-running-anywhere-built-in-service-bus-trigger/ba-p/2079995).

Please refer the below link for discussion on similar thread :

[unable to receive message from Service bus queue (Session Enabled) in Logic apps| MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/104803/unable-to-receive-message-from-service-bus-queue-s.html).